# Is there any way to prevent RouterEvent firing?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I've got an app where I needed to keep a state of a filter form in the URL string.

You can see the implementation [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d83mg3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

While changing a form value I want to set it as a URL state but `this.router.navigation([], { queryParams })` emits an event which is not needed there.

```
   data$ = merge(
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((e: NavigationEnd) => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(({ url }: NavigationEnd) => {
        const { queryParams } = this.router.parseUrl(url);
        if (queryParams['completed']) {
          queryParams['completed'] = queryParams['completed'] === 'true';
        }
        this.form.patchValue(queryParams, { emitEvent: false });
        return queryParams;
      }),
    ),
    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      tap((queryParams: Task) => {
        this.router.navigate([], { queryParams })
      })
    )
  ).pipe(
    switchMap((query?: Task) => this.getData(query))
  );
```

Is it possible somehow prevent the emitting of the navigation event?

Needs something similar with `this.form.patchValue(queryParams, { emitEvent: false });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.go(url)` is what you need.
You can always generate a proper url within `router.createUrlTree()` method

```
const url = this.router
        .createUrlTree(
          [{foo: 'bar'}],
          {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute}
        )
        .toString();
this.location.go(url);
```

Comment: Yeah, but how to apply query params? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghlc1f?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @constantant
https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createUrlTree  
https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghlc1f?file=src/app/app.component.ts but history works in non-proper way, it reloads a page

Comment: Actually it works well https://angular-ghlc1f.stackblitz.io/?name=&type=Bug&completed=true somethig wrong with the sandbox